# AD server OS upgrade

Tags: active-directory, upgrade

we are going to upgrade OS from AD 2k8 R2 to 2k12 R2 but in our environment App servers are 2003/2008 as members of the domain. which are the points check before the upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

An in-place upgrade of the existing domain controllers is not recommended. From [Upgrade Domain Controllers to Windows Server 2016](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/deploy/upgrade-domain-controllers):

> The recommended way to upgrade a domain is to promote domain
> controllers that run newer versions of Windows Server and demote the
> older domain controllers as needed. That method is preferable to
> upgrading the operating system of an existing domain controller.